# How to prove Replacement from Reflection?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

It is well known that the following [first order Bernays'(p: 20,21) reflection](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220366286_Bernays_and_Set_Theory) axiom schema together with Extensionality and Separation would prove all axioms of ZF-Reg-Power.

if $\varphi$ is a formula not using symbol $t$, and $\varphi^t$ is the formula obtained by merely bounding all quanitifiers in $\varphi$ by $\in t$, then:

$(\varphi \to \exists t: \text{ Trans} (t) \land \varphi^t)$

We are working in the first order language of set theory, so all variables are set variables.

I tried to prove replacement, my question is:

> if a formula is bounded in a transitive world, then would it maintain the truth values of the original unbounded formula? Formally, lets say that $\varphi$ is the formula $ \exists x: x = a \land  \forall m \in a\, \exists! y: \, \phi(m,y) $, then is it the case that: $$ \big{(} \varphi \land (\text { Trans}(t): \varphi^t) \implies \\\forall m \in a:  \forall y  \, ( \phi(m,y) \iff  \phi^t(m,y)) \big {)}$$

That is the intution I'm counting on, but I don't know how to prove it in an explicit manner formally.

Comment: Which axioms do you assume for this implication? Is it Zermelo set theory with Regularity?

Comment: @HanulJeon, Extensionality, Separation, Reflection.